# Cannot mirror glitch repository to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, glitch-framework

I have followed the instructions at https://glitch.com/help/how-to-sync-a-glitch-project-with-a-git-repo-on-gitlab/ to the letter, and gitlab will not mirror the repo - I get the error `Every import attempt has failed: Error importing repository https://*****@api.glitch.com/git/peaceful-buttoned-phalange into username/repo - 13:CreateRepositoryFromURL: clone cmd wait: exit status 128. Please try again`

Any clues how I can get it to sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB:** I work with the Community Engineering team at Glitch.

Your project, `~peaceful-buttoned-phalange` appears to be a private project.

While GitLab mirroring works with public Glitch projects, it seems that as of March 22nd, 2020, private external repositories can't be mirrored on a free GitLab.com account.

It seems you need at least a Bronze plan:

> The ability to mirror private external repositories and run CI/CD on them will no longer be available as of March 22, 2020, unless the repositories have been made public or you have upgraded to an eligible GitLab plan.

Source: https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/03/12/free-period-for-cicd-external-repositories/

I'll look into updating the help doc to reflect this.